# App pay - multiple payees (payment receivers)

Tags: in-app-purchase, payment

I am new to the payment area in app. Say in an App like Ritual or Open Table, I want the end user to be able to pay to multiple payees (just like the two apps I mentioned that you can pay to any listed restaurants), how can I achieve that?

From what I understand, each payee could have an merchant ID. If I want to make payment to multiple payees, do I have to obtain all their merchant ID? Or do I collect payment and then transfer to each payees?

Or, is it as app developers, we pick a payment solution (like Stripe or Braintree), and ask the participating restaurant to provide their bank info for receiving payment, and when the end users are paying, they pay directly to the restaurant's bank account through the payment solution.

Thanks.

Comment: You would need to collect the payment and then transfer funds to each payee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind the question, it's basically what I described in the last paragraph of my question

> Blockquote
>   As app developers, we pick a payment solution (like Stripe or Braintree), and ask the participating restaurant to provide their bank info for receiving payment, and when the end users are paying, they pay directly to the restaurant's bank account through the payment solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand this, why do you need multiple payee? Isn't the customer would just pay he merchant? As long as you can get the merchant ID and their account number, there should not be any issue. No?

Comment: Because if you have an food order app, you got thousands of restaurants (payees) the customer can pay to. I want to know if it is feasible by obtaining their Merchant IDs then making payments to them directly in the end user's app, or I had to collect the payment and send to each restaurant, which is going to cost a lot of fees. If obtaining their Merchant ID is feasible, please state the source, thanks in advance.